# Divergence or convergence $\sum 2^{-j}b_j$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If

$b_j>0$ and $\sum b_j$ diverges then

does the sum of

$\sum 2^{-j}b_j$

converge or diverge.

If $b_j$ diverges then limit is something that is not zero.

I would say the series

as
$\sum \frac{b_j}{2^j}$ is like the harmonic series it diverges??

Answer (score 4):

You can't say.

$\sum 1 =\infty$ and $\sum 2^j = \infty$ but $\sum 2^{-j} \times 1=1$ and $\sum 2^{-j} \times 2^j=\infty$

Comment: Hmm but I know $\sum 2^-j$ is infinity and $b_j$ is divergent so when you combine them both you get infity.... or not .....  maybe.....

Comment: @FernandoMartinez I'm sorry I don't understand your statement. $\sum 2^{-j}=1$.

Comment: Oh yes you are right....

Comment: Yes it is a geometric sum

Comment: So you have a divergent sum times a convergent sum and then you get a divergence sum because $1*\infty$ is infity??

Comment: @FernandoMartinez That is not what's going on here. There is a difference between $\sum a_j \times \sum b_j$ and $\sum a_j\times b_j$.

Comment: Ok what if I take the limit of the first partial sum and get $(-2)^j b_j$ the limit I think is infinity thus showing the sequence is not convergent. as j approach infinity

Comment: @FernandoMartinez $j$ is what you're summing over. It won't show up in the sequence of partial sums PERIOD. Also, the "limit of the first partial sum" is just the **sum**.

Comment: So what would be the correct approach???

Comment: @FernandoMartinez To what?

Comment: I guess showing the proof.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Proof of what?

Comment: I dont know of the question like how can I tell the resulting formula convergence or has no finite limit. I dont know it does not clear like the argument of the question, I dont know i am do not get the sum.